# What happened to the British universities during WWII?

Tags: world-war-two, england, social-history, britain, education

For one of my courses at university, I chose to work on the topic of British students during the Second World war.
I suppose many of them interrupted their studies to go and fight, but what was the life of those who stayed like? To what extent did the war impact their studies and daily lives?

Any answers or guidance to sources would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: @MCW: Well, I think that this question was closed a little early. When I went back to my old alma mater - Oxford - I discovered that one of the students, a German, had attempted to assainate Hitler. But failed, and was executed. But at least he tried.

Comment: Certainly some studied.  C.S. Lewis delivered a sermon, early in the war, on the subject of learning while the war was going on.